# Usage of ON or OF. Help please

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am trying to create a tagline.

> "Be an influencer **of** success."

vs

> "Be an influencer **on** success."

Which of the followings is correct?
if none is correcrt, what would be a good substitution?

Comment: Your sentence is grammatical. Whether or not it suits your purpose is something I can't say.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want your tagline to indicate that you are (or want to be) a person who influences the success of others. If that is the case then 'Be an influencer of success' is an appropriate way to say this in a tagline.